# Is there any way to disable chrome strict MIME check

Tags: google-chrome, console

I was running own website on localhost, with the server showing everything correct, Chrome gives me some errors:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://example.com' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Is there any way to skip it or disable it?

Answer (score -3):

You don't have to disable MIME checking. [See an explanation](https://developerf1.com/how-to/solving-stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type).
The problem is probably, that your stylesheet file is not accessible with the URL you defined in the link element. Maybe just a typing error. Try to click on the link in the error message and see if it can be loaded.

Check your stylesheet references in your code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/styles.css" />
```

Comment: Here I am trying to *enable* this check because I can't reproduce the issue on my machine. Every thread I find asks how to disable it and gets responses like "you shouldn't do that".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.